# What is the correct linebreak in textareas?

Tags: javascript, textarea, newline

I'm adding lines to a `textarea` using javascript. What is the correct linebreak to separate the lines?

I'm testing in Chrome (on Windows) and they all (`"\r"`, `"\n"`, `"\r\n"`) seem to work for me. I'm guessing it won't be `"\r"`, because if I'm correct only old Macs use that.

So is there a standard for this (since I will not know whether the client uses *nix / Windows)?

Answer (score 7):

Most programs/browsers will correct it for you. The only place I've ever seen it make any difference is in email headers (where `\r\n` is required) and console programs (where `\n` is newline and `\r` is rewrite-current-line).

To be "safe", you should always use `\r\n`, because if the browser/program only uses one of them, the other's a non-printable character anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I found (Professional Javascript, Holzner,S.) that the way line is ended depends on operating system, for UNIX this is `\n`, `\r` for MAC and `\r\n` for Windows.

Kolink is right, to be safe use: `\r\n`.

Comment: Latest MACs also use `\n` if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score -4):

```
<br />
```

Do you use the value at a later date in an html environment? If so you want to store it as it will be used in its final state.

Comment: Why would you put a break tag inside a textarea?

Comment: Same reason FCKeditors and TinyMCE place a break tag when you set values to a database via a text area.

As noted, if the value being set is to be returned and used within HTML the break tag is appropriate.

Comment: FCKeditor and TinyMCE are HTML WYSIWYG editors, textarea is simple plain text container. I think, it is better to use plain text linebreaks for plain texts. I prefer "\n".

Comment: I tested the condition to make sure I was not off base in my answer.

Adding two lines in a textarea then reviewing the results in the database and also how the results are displayed when rendered back into an HTML format

test line one

test line two

Will be inserted as :

test line one\r
\r
test line two\r

But when rendered back to an HTML environment, you will see:

test line one test line two 

If this is your goal (ignoring the breaks when recalled) then you've got your answer. 

Otherwise, go with the "return" and "new" line characters as noted (\r\n)